# Execute a script on IIS recycle

Tags: iis, iis-7

Is there to tie a script to IIS recycle process so it can be executed before recycle action takes place?

The goal of this script would be to take a server out of Load Balancer before the recycle occurs and add it back after the recycle.

I know that I could have a script that among other things can call a pool recycle. But I am looking to see if the script can be called when the IIS automated recycle is initiated.

I am open to other suggestions as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any hooks that allow us to run a script before the recycling takes place.

Even if IIS logs all recycle events in the event log and you have a service to monitor the event log in real-time for such event. I doubt it could do anything before the actual recycling takes place.

Recycling an application pool can be a very quick operation, there may be not enough time to change the settings on the load balancer.

A normal recycling of an application pool should not result in any down-time of that site, so there is no need to take it out of the load balancing pool.

As you mentioned, if you are really concerned about this. Don't let IIS recycle itself. Write a script to take the host of out load balancing, then recycle the pool and add the host back in.

IIS has a hook to run a script (or any executable) when the App pool fails, but that's different from recycling. Those settings are under 'Rapid-Fail Protection'